# Navigating through SQL Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I'm using the following code:

```
//Handles every game and their attributes
function handleGames(){
    sql.query('SELECT id FROM games', function (err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log(String(err).error.bgWhite);
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            /** ["id"]
                ["starttime"]
                ["status"]
                ["ct_name"]
                ["ct_avatar"]
                ["ct_steamid"]
                ["ct_bet"]
                ["t_name"]
                ["t_avatar"]
                ["t_steamid"]
                ["t_bet"]           **/

                var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
                //console.log(String(timeNow).info.bgWhite);

                //Game Expiration
                //0 = Open | 4 = Expired | 5 = Generic Error

                //Generic error --> Expired
                if(rows[i]["status"] == 5){
                    sql.query('UPDATE games SET status = 4 WHERE id = "' + rows[i]["id"] + '"', function (err, rows){
                        if(err) console.log(String(err).error.bgWhite);
                        console.log(("Updating status for game " + rows[i]["id"] + " to 4").info.bgWhite);
                    });
                }

                //Gamestatus set to expired if game has lasted 5m (300s)
                if(((rows[i]["starttime"] + 300) >= timeNow) && (rows[i]["status"] == 0)){
                    sql.query('UPDATE games SET status = 4 WHERE id = "' + rows[i]["id"] + '"', function (err, rows){
                        if(err) console.log(String(err).error.bgWhite);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

With the following data:

[image]

The program is written for Node, and should change the status of any game which has lasted 5 minutes (300s), however I'm having trouble navigating with keys. **The game status isn't updated.**

**[JSON Version](https://csgovoid.net/api/v2/games)**

---

**SQL Export:**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Apr 28, 2016 at 01:25 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.26-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `csgovoid_data`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `games`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `starttime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = Open, 1 = In progress, 2 = CT Win, 3 = T Win, 4 = Expired, 5 = Generic error',
  `ct_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ct_avatar` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ct_steamid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ct_bet` float NOT NULL,
  `t_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `t_avatar` longtext NOT NULL,
  `t_steamid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `t_bet` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `games`
--

INSERT INTO `games` (`id`, `starttime`, `status`, `ct_name`, `ct_avatar`, `ct_steamid`, `ct_bet`, `t_name`, `t_avatar`, `t_steamid`, `t_bet`) VALUES
(3, 1461862619, 0, 'Robinlemon > CSGOVoid.net', 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c5/c5ef952e8bd4ff79afcecb9971ec831b21707be7_full.jpg', 76561198065346589, 3, 'Yuuta', 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/73/734a259213585f56c15631a56b127018710d2e34_full.jpg', 76561198052096214, 3);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: are you getting any error on terminal???Post it here if any!

Comment: No error, just wont update the status. Am I using the key correctly

Comment: are you getting `Updating status for game ....` on terminal??/

Comment: no, and printing rows[i]["status"] to the terminal produces 'undefined'

Comment: add console.log in 2nd if...
and call these two queries in nesting callbacks....and 
since you are using loop and in each iteration you are performing query on currently iterated element so,use async in order to achieve blocking code..

see asynchronous behavior of nodejs

Comment: I don't understand what your saying, I just want to get each piece of data in each row per for loop itterate and process it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110566/discussion-between-vkstack-and-robinlemon).

Comment: see the answer perhaps that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so `((new Date()).getTime()-starttime)/1000` will give u time duration in seconds
can you post you code in any online javascript editor like plunker !
u here?

```
INSERT INTO `games` (`id`, `starttime`, `status`, `ct_name`, `ct_avatar`, `ct_steamid`, `ct_bet`, `t_name`, `t_avatar`, `t_steamid`, `t_bet`) VALUES 
(3, 1461862619, 0, 'Robinlemon > CSGOVoid.net', 'steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/…', 76561198065346589, 3, 'Yuuta', 'cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/…', 76561198052096214, 3);
```

this is in your dump sql! 
which is inserting an entity with id (with AUTO_INCREMENT) 3!!
so for next inserts AUTO_INCREMENT will be 4!!!

if you want to change that you remove the row in the table and the reset AUTO_INCREMENT counter

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```